# SSH to a docker container

Tags: ssh, docker

I'm new to docker and I don't manage to connect to a container.

If I understand properly I have to connect to SSH to my actual host then use this :

```
docker exec -it pihole-pihole1(name_of_the_container) command
```

but then when I do this :

```
docker exec -it pihole-pihole1 sudo nano /etc/pihole/adlists.list
```

I have this error :

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.29/containers/pihole-pihole1/exec: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

How should I proceed ?

Comment: Are you running the command as root user or normal user ? If normal user, make sure you have added him into `docker` group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your user to Docker group on the host machine:

`sudo usermod -aG docker <username>`

Logout, login again, it should work. Otherwise you need to insert `sudo` before all of your docker commands.